# Imagemagick montage is creating corrupted filenames in the display command

Tags: imagemagick

The Tile Verb in ImageMagick display is not working correctly due to montage corrupting the filenames,

```
ls -1 home*.png
home_10.png
home11_biggerMB.png
home_12_1600.png
home_12.png
home_15_212_baths.png
home_16_small.png
home_18_48x32.png
home_19_8h.png
home_20_8h.png
home_212_2.png
home_21_side_patio.png
home_25_1728.png
home_25_1732.png
home26_1728.png
home_27_1728.png
home_27_1728_with_walls.png
home_3.png
home4.png
home_5.png
home_6_mbedroom.png
home7.png
home_9_mbed.png
home_bob_fail_redo.png
home_k_g_together.png
home_mbed_9.png
home_plan_58x34.png
```

- use montage to create a single image with a small image of each of the above files.

  ```
   montage home*.png home3.miff
  ```
- display the file home3.miff

  ```
   display home3.miff &
  ```

Use Mouse Right-Click to get "Tile Verb" and then scroll to "Load" to see the Image full size.

I get a notice that the file fails to open because the filenames don't have correct line breaks. The file names are strung together with a "y umlaut" looking character. I get the error blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.

This worked fine until I did a new install of Ubuntu 20.04. All previous versions never had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/magick --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-3 Q16 x86_64 2021-02-27 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype gvc jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr png raqm tiff x xml zlib

This version does not have the above issue.

Comment: The above binary is self-contained so no package is needed.  https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php is the location

Comment: You mean the appimage version from that page?

Comment: Yes. The appimage version.